How to create a POST payload from a slice
Creating payload for the array,POST API call.
pipeline   []struct {
        Test string `json:"$Test"`
    } `json:"pipeline"`

JSON example
{

    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$Test": "test"
      }

    ]
}


For the above struct want to create a POST call request payload like the above JSON structure. I tried different options, but it's not working. What would be the right syntax?

Edit the question to show what you tried.  Describe how that failed to solve the problem.

You can try the following code
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type TestInt struct{
    Test string `json:"$Test"`
}
type Payload struct{
    PipeLine []TestInt `json:"pipeline"`
}

func main() {
    pl:=Payload{
        PipeLine: []TestInt{
            {
                Test:"test",
            },
            
        },
    }
    js,_:=json.Marshal(pl)
    fmt.Println(string(js))
}

See Working link
